# Proving a bounded and continuous function $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ assumes its maximum value on $[a, b].$

Tags: real-analysis

The proof starts like this:

Set $M = \sup\{f(x) : x \in [a, b]\}.$ For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $y_n \in [a, b]$ s.t. $M - \frac{1}{n} < f(y_n) \leq M.$ Hence $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y_n) = M$ by the squeeze lemma.

What I don't understand is why the left inequality in the second sentence is true. I haven't been able to logically reason why it's true nor do I have any intuition about why it's true. I understand that the right inequality holds since $y_n$ is in $\{f(x) : x \in [a, b]\}$ and $M = \sup S$.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is your definition of compact? Closed and bounded?

Comment: $M$ is the least upper bound. Therefore, $M-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound so you can find the $y_n$ that makes the inequality true.

Comment: @GuidoA. It doesn't matter which definition of compact is used. By the way, closed and bounded sets are only compact in complete metric spaces.

Comment: @JohnDouma I think you mean totally bounded and complete. Also, it **does** matter because it limits (or otherwise widens) the amount of resources to use in an (understandable) answer. This can be said without a mention of compactness, that I can agree on.

Comment: @GuidoA. No. Consider $\{q\in\mathbb Q: 0\le q^2\le 2\}$. This is closed and bounded in $\mathbb Q$ but is not compact. Also, the definitions of compact are equivalent in a metric space.

Comment: @JohnDouma the rationals are certainly not complete.

Comment: @GuidoA. This is a subset of $\mathbb Q$ which is closed and bounded but not compact.

Comment: @JohnDouma I have never stated that closed and bounded implies compact outside of the context of this answer. As I said before, a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded (bounded is not enough). I fail to see the point of your remarks.

Comment: @GuidoA. There were two points. Closed and bounded sets are not compact and it doesn't matter which definition of compactness you use. Both statements are true.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, sets are compact if and only if they are closed and bounded. This is a standard definition for introductory courses, even if it does not hold in a general context. So I would contest both statements.

Comment: @GuidoA. This is not standard in a first course through the Math department. It is often an incorrect simplification for engineers, economists and computer scientists.

Comment: @JohnDouma Not for all universities, at least. I know the math curriculum in the US usually involves a first stage of computation oriented courses (Calculus I - III if I recall correctly), to then move onto 'proof based' analysis courses. I can only speak for my personal experience: my first course at university involved (what you would call proof based) multivariable calculus, and we defined compact sets as closed an bounded. Expecting the level of mathematical maturity needed to grasp open covers in a first course would be unfair, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true because the supremum is the *least* upper bound.

Indeed, suppose there were some $n$ such that for all $y \in [a,b]$, $M - 1/n \geq f(y)$. Then $M - 1/n$ would be an upper bound of $f([a,b])$ and *strictly less* than $M$. But that contradicts that $M$ is the least upper bound of $f([a,b])$.

The intuition is this: if you decrease the supremum of a set $S$ by "a little bit", then there's some member $x$ of the set that's then greater than the decreased value. If there weren't, then the decreased value would upper bound $S$ and be less than $S$'s supremum, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Look, it’s just a definition of supremum 
We can approach to it as close as we want: if $M$ is supremum then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find element $x$ from your set such that $M-\epsilon<x$

Comment: In your case $1/n$ plays an epsilon role